# App Install stuck on "Install" on Android studio(physical device)

Tags: android-studio, installation, adb

I am having the issue where My app gets stuck on "install" on android studio

The same happens if i try to install the app via ADB command line it gets stuck on "Perfomring Streamlined Install"

This question has been asked on the site alot but none of the answers there work,

I am running Android studio 4.1.1, My device is a LG Velvet on android 10

if i copy the APK to the phone it installs fine

Things I have tried

Restarting Devices,

restarting software(Android Srudio etc.),

using a diffrent USB cable

I have uninstalled my devices USB drivers and reinstalled

Tried changing gradle etc.

Revoking USB debugging auth,

unplugging the phone and re plugging it

I am getting this on my Android studio aswell after awhile
Timed out waiting for process (com.smartpractice.smartpracticesmartapp) to appear on lge-lm_g910-LMG910

Here are the links for questions here on SO where the same question has been asked

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867985/app-hang-on-install-in-android-studio/36481028#:~:text=I%20fixed%20this%20issue%20by,time%2C%20the%20software%20started%20correctly.&text=I%20was%20stuck%20on%20install,the%20phone%2C%20and%20it%20worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867985/app-hang-on-install-in-android-studio/36481028#:%7E:text=I%20fixed%20this%20issue%20by,time%2C%20the%20software%20started%20correctly.&text=I%20was%20stuck%20on%20install,the%20phone%2C%20and%20it%20worked).

[Android Studio not installing App on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969611/android-studio-not-installing-app-on-device)

Answer (score 1):

For some devices, `adb` can only push apps if USB file transfer is enabled: Go to `USB Preferences` and make sure `File Transfer` is ticked under `Use USB for`.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on this option and you are good to go otherwise try to chage your testing device

[image]

Comment: Thanks FOr the Help, That option isnt in my Developer options for some reason but I did solve the issue by connectiong ADB to my device Via WIFI